# convergence radius $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a^{(k^{2})}x^{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the convergence radius of this series in respect of $a \in \mathbb{C}$?

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a^{(k^{2})}x^{k}$$

I am studying math in the first semester. I had no problems solving similar problems but I am stuck on this one.

$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a^{(k+1)^2}x^{k+1}}{a^{k^2}x^k}\right|=$ $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|a^{2k+1}x\right|$

This is what I got with the ratio test. How do I continue?

Comment: What's the limit when $|a|=1$? What about when it's larger or smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

The limit is further simplified to $$|x|\cdot \lim_{k\to\infty}|a|^{2k+1}$$Now, for $x\ne 0$, what happens when $|a|<1$ or $|a|>1$? (The case $|a|=1$ is also interesting as the test may go inclusive!)

Comment: Oh, it's that easy, idk how I forgot that. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck!